# How to fork a project in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Say you create a project. Then you want to do something else. You want to create another project that uses all the files of the previous project. You then modify it a little bit.

In vb.net it's simple. You just copy the vbproj file and that's it.

In objective-c copying the xcproj will result in a project file that won't compile.

Solution?

Note:

1. I do not want to do simple copy. If I do simple copy changes will not be propagated. I want if the fork change so will the original file.
2. As far as I know changing the project file name will make the project fail to compile. So just copying the project file doesn't work unless I do something wrong.

I think it's utterly ridiculous that there is no easy way to make the project work after changing the name of the xcodeproj file? I can't even open that xcodeproj file in textedit. In vb.net I can hack the project file straight. Why not in xcode?

Comment: Even here it is simple, copy the folder and rename it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If it were that simple I wouldn't ask. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options which I would prefer :-

If there are classes which are constant and are not changing, you can make library which is called as Cocoa Touch Static Library

OR

Just copy folder to another location, rename application name and changes you want to do and run it!

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: Renaming the project file name will make the project stop working. I do not want to copy folder. I want the new project to refer to old files so if one changes the change will propagate.

Comment: @SharenEayrs Yes, so in my answer I said, create Cocoa Touch Static Library by pasting that common files there and which you can re-use same files everywhere you required.

Comment: Basically I have to relink hundreds of files by reference :(.... I'll wait for easier way.

Comment: +1 for reasonably good answer. I'll see in a few days if there is an even better one.

Comment: @SharenEayrs Did you find any good and simple solution for same?

Comment: Not yet. I noticed I can just copy that project files and open the copy. However, the xcode then think that I program for mac 64 instead of IOS

Answer (score 3):

I long for the day when you can simply choose "save as template" from Xcode(!)
In the meantime it might save you some headache to check out [Project Duplicator](https://itunes.apple.com/no/app/project-duplicator-for-xcode/id467950482?l=nb&mt=12) from the AppStore. I haven't tried it out myself yet, but it sounds like it's designed to do exactly what you're asking for.

If you want to do it the manually way you could duplicate the folder with all corresponding files in the Finder and go about renaming everything from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple targets for your project.
look at this [link](http://blog.just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/).

Comment: +1 good enough. I just want the project to be a little independent.

Comment: Another solution is that you can create a static library of your files, which you are going to reuse in your application. Lets assume that you found an issue with your code, if you have 2 separate projects you need to fix that issue/bug on both projects, with static library you just change the code once since you have the library refference in your destination project.The same is with multiple targets, but library would give your app more independence I think.